# no email alert from exception_notification plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app is running on Rails 2.2.2

As far as i can tell, there are 3 versions of the exception_notification plugin.

- One for Rails 3.0 *(https://github.com/rails/exception_notification)*
- One for Rails versions from 2.3 up to, but not including, 3.0 *(https://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/2-3-stable)*
- One for Rails versions prior to 2.3 *(https://github.com/rails/exception_notification/tree/pre-2-3)*

I have been all over looking for a workable solution. One of the problems is that numerous problems are identified without making reference to which version is causing the error. Solutions that work for one version are given for another version which does not work.

Current Status: back to fresh install and original recommended configuration

- the plugin has been uninstalled and then reinstalled.
- all the potential fixes have been removed
- "include ExceptionNotifiable" was added to the top of my ApplicationController
- "ExceptionNotifier.exception_recipients = %w(myid@live.com)" was added to environment.rb

Action Mailer is sending other emails but I am not receiving the exception emails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote up [detailed instructions](http://paulschreiber.com/blog/2010/05/10/handling-rails-errors/) on setting up exception notification (and custom error pages) with Rails 2.3 on my blog.

Comment: Thanks, Paul... but i am running 2.2.2 not 2.3.x. Configuration for Rails 2.2 is different from 2.3

Comment: Shouldn't be. And: can you not upgrade to 2.3.10?

Comment: i just upgraded our app to 2.3.8 so this post wound up becoming the right answer.